# Determine if this series : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n-1}{(\sqrt2)^n}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to determine if this series converge or diverge using the **d'Alembert's ratio test**

Using the ratio test I have that:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2(n+1)-1}{(\sqrt2)^{n+1}}\frac{(\sqrt2)^n}{2n-1}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2(n+1)-1}{(\sqrt2)^{n}2n-1}$

How can I proceed from there? or if I was wrong tell me the mistake please.

Comment: Your cancellation has an error. $\sqrt{2}$ shouldn’t have the power $n$ In the denominator

Comment: Yes, i knew i made a mistake somewhere. I fixed it and i was able to get to the result. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\dfrac{2n+1}{2n-1}\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot 1=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<1,
\end{align*}
so it is convergent by the ratio test.

Comment: i see, sorry for such a stupid question. Didnt realise about that, i am studying a lot of these infinite series and sometimes i get confused.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2(n+1)-1}{(\sqrt2)^{n+1}}\frac{(\sqrt2)^n}{2n-1}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n+1)}{\sqrt2 (2n-1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}<1$$

Thus the series converges.